# Transaction not showing up in Ropsten Etherscan

Tags: transactions, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ropsten

Around an hour back , I initiated a transaction on Ropsten network . I used Ethereum wallet for the transaction. Attaching a screenshot of the transaction below . But till now I cannot see this transaction on Ropsten network

[image: Transaction screenshot]

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Is your node connected to the blockchain? Check peers number on bottom left. Or maybe you are not sync

Comment: Yes the node was connected to the blockchain , I could see around 4 to 5 peers

Comment: Are you sure it's Ropsten? By default its rinkeby that wallet supports.

Comment: I am sure the network is Ropsten . Today again I initiated another transaction with hash as 0x1942c72365864396f12cf469f8aaddacd5f2691c396f8966755044465354abf1 and it cannot be seen on the ropsten network